# Regular expressionin Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

This is my string

```
'SEPA1,30-NOV-17;SEPA2,30-NOV-17;SEPA3,30-NOV-17;'
```

I need out like 'SEPA1,SEPA2,SEPA3' using Regular expression.

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ('SEPA1,30-NOV-17;SEPA2,30-NOV-17;SEPA3,30-NOV-17;',
                        '([^,]+)(\1)+', '')
FROM dual;
```

This query is not working: it leaves the input string unchanged. Also, I am looking for a regular expression solution (in particular, no use of a CONNECT BY LEVEL query to split the string into pieces).

Comment: Please help WITHOUT using LEVEL

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful. Tell us what actually happens - an error, wrong results? It would also help if you were clear about the rules - it looks like within each semi-colon-separated value you want everything up to the first comma? Or just any fragment starting `SEPA`? Or something else?

Comment: Why are you using `REGEXP_REPLACE`?

Comment: there is no error I need to like SEPA1,SEPA2,SEPA3 using SQL query

Comment: Hi  Bob Jarvis , You can use any function. but I need result like SEPA1,SEPA2,SEPA3 for given string 'SEPA1,30-NOV-17;SEPA2,30-NOV-17;SEPA3,30-NOV-17;'

Comment: The input string seems to use the semicolon as a token **terminator** rather than *separator* (the last token is terminated by a semicolon). In the desired output you show the comma used as a separator rather than a terminator. Is that really the requirement? It's quite odd to change the kind of delimiter convention between the input and the output.

Comment: Also: can the "sub-tokens" between the comma and the semicolon contain additional commas? If so, how should that be handled? (It doesn't need to be handled if it can never happen, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MT0 has already provided the correct solution (most likely, but see the discussion of commas - perhaps escaped - within token values). Let me explain here what is happening in your attempt - you may find this helpful.

`[^,]+` in the search pattern means one or more non-comma characters. This part is probably OK, but it raises two questions.

1. Can the input string contain substrings like `'SEPA6,;'`? This would be how a "row in a table" (presented as a single string, where "rows" are terminated by semicolon and within each row, values are separated by comma), where the "date" is `null`. So - the question is, can there be `null` dates in your string, which would be represented by `,;` with nothing between the comma and the semicolon? If that is possible, you would need to change the `+` quantifier to `*`, to allow **zero** or more non-comma characters before the semicolon.
2. Can there ever be a comma, a few characters, another comma, a few more characters, and then a semicolon? Presumably not in the "date" portion of each token; but where you show SEPA1 etc., whatever they mean, could there be a comma in the name (probably escaped, something like `SE","TG`)? In that case, you really want something like what you did, with the negated character class. The Answer posted by MT0 will delete everything from the FIRST comma (even if it's in the middle of the "name") to the semicolon.

Then, in your attempt you use a lookback reference, `(\1)`, in the search pattern. There is no reason for that; you want to match non-commas followed by a semicolon, so that's what you must write in the search pattern. There is no repeating of the substring of non-commas found by the first part of the pattern.

Replacing something with `null` is the default for `regexp_replace`, so you may - optionally - leave out the last argument - the `''` in your attempt.

So, your solution can be rewritten like so:

```
  ... regexp_replace(input_string, '[^,]*;')
```

(I left out the last argument, which was `''` in your attempt - that is the default third argument anyway; but you may prefer to show it for clarity. OK either way.)

This will leave a comma at the END of the output string. I asked you a question in the Comments - it is not clear why you are changing from a terminator (the semicolon in the inputs) to a separator (the comma in the output); normally the delimiter should be of the same kind, either terminator in both input and output, or separator in both. (It is also odd that you are changing from semicolon to comma as the primary delimiter, but you must have your reasons.) In any case, that's why MT0 needed to wrap the return string from the regexp replace operation within a call to `trim()`, to remove the trailing comma.

A note about efficiency:

If you can have commas (perhaps escaped) within the "values" in your input string, the solution will have to be more complicated to handle all the possibilities. If commas are not possible in the "date" portion that you must eliminate from your input, but they are possible elsewhere, then the solution you were trying (which I fixed for you a little earlier in this Answer) will produce the required result; MT0's Answer will not, since it will start at the first comma after a semicolon, regardless of where it is.

However, if there are no commas anywhere except as true delimiters, then MT0's solution will be correct, and much faster than replacing `[^,]*;`. Regular expressions are (very) slow by nature, and writing them efficiently is exceptionally important. The difference between the solutions seems minor, so let's see what it is.

When you search for `'[^,]*;'` the regexp engine will try to find a match from the first character. It's not a comma... it reads the second character in, the third, ... and then it finds a comma before it finds a semicolon. So the pattern can't be matched. Then the engine tries to find a match from the second character, which also fails when the first comma is encountered. Etc. This will take a lot of time.

If you search for `',.*?;'`, the engine starts at the first character in the input string. The first character is not a comma, so there will be no match. The engine can already move on to the second character. It is not a comma either, to match the first character in the regexp pattern, so there will be no match at the second character of the input string either. These conclusions are drawn much faster, so the actual matches are found much faster too. MT0's solution differs from yours by a leading comma - that helps the regexp engine a lot.

Comment: String  contains '<Invoice#,INV Date>' I need only invoice number with comma separated. 
The explanation is awesome. Please share the me link so I can learn more on the regular expression. if possible.

Comment: Hi, I have one more question is it possible to get the same result with only SUBSTR function. In SEPA style sheet REG EXP is not accepting.

Comment: @ArunGoWdA - If you can’t use regular expression (which is odd - are you sure?) you will need some sort of recursion. In the question you ruled out CONNECT BY LEVEL. (Why?) The only other option I know of is a recursive WITH clause, is that OK?

Answer (score 2):

Use the regular expression `,.*?;` to find each comma and then the minimum amount of characters until the next semi-colon to match the portion of the string you want to replace:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         TRAILING ',' FROM
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           'SEPA1,30-NOV-17;SEPA2,30-NOV-17;SEPA3,30-NOV-17;',
           ',.*?;',
           ','
         )
       ) AS sepas
FROM   DUAL
```

**Output**:

```
SEPAS
-----------------
SEPA1,SEPA2,SEPA3
```

Comment: this Helped me a lot. Thanks for the output. rather than pasting the questions in others site. from now on I will always prefer the stackoverflow.